# Need clarification in Pareto Distribution Code in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Can you please explain 'output.T' in code? I have searched on google, but could not find any answers to help to know the code better. The code is to plot Pareto distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pareto

xm = 1 # scale 
alphas = [1, 2, 3] # shape parameters
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)

output = np.array([pareto.pdf(x, scale = xm, b = a) for a in alphas])
plt.plot(x, output.T)
plt.show()
```

In this code, what does output.T represent? Specifically, what is T here?

Comment: `T` transposes output ... it converts rows to columns basically

Comment: FYI: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case it looks like you'll have a list of lists converted into an array. The `.T` takes a transpose, similar to the operation on matrices from mathematics. You can see the difference via:
`output.T.shape` 
vs.
`output.shape`

here is a small example:

```
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a.shape
(1, 3)
>>> a.T
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> a.T.shape
(3, 1)
```

Note this doesn't really have anything to do with the Pareto distribution ***per se*** except maybe for the fact that Pareto supported vectorization but the `.T` operation in an operation on `np.array` object so that is what you'd want to be looking for in docs.